# Automatically create documentation by reading function comments (PHP)

Tags: php, documentation

Let's say I have:

```
class myclass {

    /*
     * This function, bla bla bla
     */
    function myclass()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    /*
     * This function, bla bla bla
     */
    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }

    /*
     * This function, bla bla bla
     */
    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}
```

By using `get_class_methods(new myclass());` I can get the classes.

Now my question is this: can I read the comments from the class function into a string? 
So I can create auto generated documentation.

Comment: Use [PHPDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/), like everybody else does; but the docblocks should come ___before___ the method definitions, not inside them

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker I know PHPDocumentor, but I would like to make something myself :-)
Updated the example, I'm still wondering how I could get those comments :-P

Comment: If you want to reinvent the wheel, use [reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), specifically the `getDocComment()` method.... but note, `In order to retrieve a comment with this method, the comment must be imediately before the class, function or method`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get access to comments from PHP if the target file is included with include, include_once, require or require_once because php-parser strips all comments out of code.

If you need to do it and don't want to use PHPDocumentor or Doxygen, but want to do it yourself, you need to read the target file using file_get_contents or any other reading method and parse this code yourself using reguar expressions of other method of your choise(for example using this library - https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). And parsing the code yourself you can get all information you need from comments.

But it is not so easy task so my advice is to use PHPDocumentor :P

[EDIT 2021-07-08]
Since PHP 5 you can do this pretty easily using [ReflectionClass::getDocComment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

Comment: Yeah. I Like PHPDoc's standard for documenting :) +1

Comment: Thanks @dmikam! and yes, I know I'm quite stubborn, but really would like to try it ;-P